# Asus P7P55D-E LX motherboard -- over 16GB RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard

We have a FreeNAS server with a P7P55D-E LX motherboard.

We've added a lot more disk space since building, and need to upgrade the RAM.

Specs say 16GB is the max ... (4x4GB) ... but is this true since now there are 8GB sticks? Can we put 4x8GB in there?

Comment: To my surprise, there are people using 32GB on P55-based boards.  This is promising, but since ASUS never verified it with your board, you simply will have to try and see.

Comment: Yeah, we may just have to try it.

Comment: The memory controller is actually in the CPU (not the motherboard).  What's the model of the processor?

Comment: @Jason - Intel Core i3-540 Clarkdale 3.06GHz LGA 1156 73W Dual-Core Desktop Processor

Comment: **Your CPU doesn't even support more then 16GB this was easily confirmed on Intel's website.**

Answer (score 4):

With an Intel P55-based motherboard, the memory controller is actually in the processor.  According to [Intel's datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/datasheet/core-i5-600-i3-500-pentium-6000-datasheet-vol-1.pdf) (page 12) for the processor you're using, "the largest memory capacity possible is 16 GB".

Although, forum posts such as [this one](http://forums.overclockers.com.au/showpost.php?p=15372907&postcount=9) seem to contradict this.  I guess the old adage of "try and see" applies here.