# Asus motherboard / FreeBSD memory issue

Tags: memory, motherboard, freebsd, freenas

We have a FreeNAS server, **Asus P7P55D-E LX** motherboard, 6GB of RAM.

We want to upgrade it to 16GB.

We installed 2 x 8GB RAM from Amazon: [Crucial Ballistix Sport 16GB Kit (8GBx2) DDR3 1600 MT/s (PC3-12800) CL9 @1.5V UDIMM 240-Pin Memory BLS2KIT8G3D1609DS1S00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006YG9EEW)

Machine sees 16GB in BIOS, boots FreeNAS, but then FreeBSD throws up this error:

```
Starting ntpd.
/etc/rc: WARNING: failed precmd routine for vmware_guestd
Starting smbd.
panic: vm_page_insert: page already inserted
cpuid = 2

Fatal trap 9: general protection fault while in kernel mode​
```

It works fine with our old 6GB of RAM.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Try different new RAM.

Comment: Did you update the BIOS?  The last BIOS update in 2011 improved memory compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a followup question to your [original question here](https://superuser.com/questions/796495/asus-p7p55d-e-lx-motherboard-over-16gb-ram).

So assuming we're talking about the same [Core i3-540](http://ark.intel.com/products/46473/Intel-Core-i3-540-Processor-4M-Cache-3_06-GHz), you'll notice that it only supports DDR3-1066 or DDR3-1333, not the DDR3-1600 you purchased.

Comment: Shouldn't it just downclock the ram to the lower speeds? I've never seen a problem with higher speed ram than the system requires, it just always ran underclocked.

Comment: @Stephanie Yep!  But only if there's an SPD timing for it.  Most of the time there is, but not always.

Comment: @Stephanie - The memory might not function at a lower clock speed.  Its not just the moetherboard and cpu that must supoprt a memory frequency the memory must also.

Answer (score 0):

Flash memtest86 to a USB and run it, run a few passes to see if its the ram or the motherboard that's giving you trouble

Comment: Can you please expand this answer.  Its actually good advice but its more of a comment then an answer at this point.