# Is it possible to install 8GB sticks in a P7P55D Deluxe motherboard?

Tags: windows-7, memory, motherboard

I've bought a stick of 8GB of RAM and I'm trying to install it on my P7P55D Deluxe, but until now, I've got no success. The manual of the board shows some models of compatible RAM sticks and most of them has 4GB of RAM but I haven't found anything that says that a 8GB stick couldn't work with it.

Some people in some forums said that they were able to install 2 sticks of 8GB, so I assume it's possible.

Comment: Are you adding 16 GB, or did you remove the memory already installed?  The processor contains the memory controller, what is the model of the processor?  What is the model of the memory you purchased?

Comment: @Jason The memory stick I purchased is the Kingston KVR1333D3N9/8G. The processor is an Intel i5-760. I removed the memory already installed.

Comment: The specs on Asus's say "4 x DIMM, Max. 16 GB" so I kinda suspect its not supported at all.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The problem is that some people claim they were able to install 32GB of RAM on it. Jason's answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/q/796495/124630) points it out.

Comment: And he didn't get it working either. Its anecdotal

Comment: Did you update the BIOS?  The last 2011 update improved memory compatibility.

Comment: @Ramhound Read the question and my previous commentary again.

Comment: @Ramhound Read the manual. Read this: **Some people in some forums said that they were able to install 2 sticks of 8GB** and [this](http://superuser.com/a/796517/124630).

Comment: @Ramhound [1 8GB stick, check the manual now.](http://imgur.com/a/8rVzZ) I've been able to install it. :-)

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is that you didn't see that the manual **clearly** doesn't say that **only** those RAM sticks combinations would work.

Answer (score 0):

The Asus P7P55D Deluxe can support up to 16 GB of DDR3 RAM, so you should be fine with 2x  Kingston KVR1333D3N9/8G

Comment: It must be something to do with your bios As Jason Stated before

Answer (score 0):

The manual for the P7P55D Deluxe clearly states the maximum is 4GB per slot, so your two 8GB sticks will never work.  I have the same MB in my security system PC and I also wanted to try 2x8gb, but a quick peek at the manual showed this was not possible so I don't even intend to try.